# My time is as a moderator drawing to a close

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

Just a heads up: I'm considering stepping down in the near future. Obviously, I'm not around often any more, and I can't really be of any use to the site. I'm not making this decision lightly as I still feel a "connection" to the site/community, but it's for the best.

All the best to everyone, especially my potential replacement(s).

Comment: Not nice that SE strips greetings even on meta.

Comment: Iirc that's just on posting. You should be able to edit it back in. At worst, you can use HTML comments as a hack.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't bother to, but nice to know it can be worked around where needed. I felt like this post was a bit too formal without any greetings.

Answer (score 5):

I fully understand you buddy. 100%. Same reason I stepped down and let someone else help out. Between life changes, family, work and more, it has become VERY hard to maintain the same level of productivity and engagement we had when we started. Just stay positive and you will do great champ. Big hugs.

Comment: Thanks! I certainly can't keep any more, and I feel like things are changing on the network in general anyway, so now's a good time for me to make that step.

Answer (score 2):

Well sorry to see you go.  I'm just a newbe here and I could never imagine myself having that level of expertise to be able to answer technical questions 'gratis'.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that! I'll still pop in periodically <3